# Is it possible to search text within text-files using Catfish?

Tags: file-search

I want to find a line in system files - that is I need to scan a lot of files for that.

I learned that I can use

```
 grep -r <word> *
```

replacing  with the needed expression.

Can Catfish do that kind of search?

(I am in Linux Mint 15 Xfce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the `catfish` website:

> Catfish is a search gui powered by locate and find behind the scenes, with autocompletion from zeitgeist and locate. the advanced options allow filtering by date and file type. the interface is intentionally lightweight and simple, using only gtk+.

So, no, `catfish` is a frontend to `locate` and `find` neither of which search *through* files but only look at file names.

Answer (score 1):

In Catfish 1.0.2 at least, click on the gear (upper right button) and select Fulltext Search.  That'll do what you want.